# How to save model of Spark sklearn model?

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I am training a random forest model of sklearn, wrapped in `from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV`.
When I try to save the model, I get the `SPARK-5063 error`.

I tried using both `pickle` and `joblib`.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import pickle
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV

def main():
...
    regr_rf_cv = GridSearchCV(sc=spark.sparkContext, 
                      estimator=regr, 
                      n_jobs=20,
                      cv=5, 
                      verbose=5,
                      param_grid={})
    regr_rf_cv.fit(train_df, train_target_df)
    save_model(regr_rf_cv , "rf_model", "/data/saved_model")

def save_model(model, model_name, path):
      with open(path + model_name + ".pkl", 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(model, f)
        print("Model was saved in: " + path + model_name + ".pkl"

main()
```

Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference `SparkContext` from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. `SparkContext` can only be used on the driver, not in code run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Answer (score 0):

Try using joblib:

```
def save_model_joblib(save_path, model_object):
    os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)

    currdate = date.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")
    file_name = f"{currdate}.obj"
    out_file_path = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)

    joblib.dump(model_object, out_file_path)
```